# Android , Firebase JSON string

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to Android and Firebase.. I have stored data in Firebase DB by importing JSON file. Now I am trying to retrieve data in Android textbook. But I am unable to stringify the JSON data, which I did in JavaScript. Also I am not able to get the data in the numerical order, which I am getting in JavaScript.

Following the code DB structure:

[image]

```
 // Initialize with secondary app.
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this /* Context */, SITEINFO, "secondary_SITEINFO");
    // Retrieve secondary app.
    FirebaseApp secondary_siteinfo = FirebaseApp.getInstance("secondary_SITEINFO");
    // Get the database for the other app.
    FirebaseDatabase secondaryDB_siteinfo = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(secondary_siteinfo);

    final Query query1 = secondaryDB_siteinfo.getReference("");



    fetch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {



           query1.orderByChild("01-SITEID").equalTo("EKM01").addListenerForSingleValueEvent


                   (new ValueEventListener() {
               @Override
               public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {





                   String Value1 = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
```

My Javascript code

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('/').orderByChild("01-SITEID").equalTo(input_final)
ref.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
var obj = JSON.stringify(snapshot.val());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase native SDKs for Android and iOS return native types for their respective language. They don't return JSON, nor do they have built-in options to convert the data they return to JSON.

If you need to convert the Java objects to JSON for your app, you will have to implement it yourself (or find a library).

---

#### Update

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

To process the result of your query (in the correct order), use `DataSnapshot.getChildren()`:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
  for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: DataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    System.out.println(childSnapshot.getKey()+": "+childSnapshot.child("01-SITEID").getValue());
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Frank.. any sample page... if you can guide me thru.

Comment: Also is there any way I could retrieve data sequently in android.. Am I missing some thing in the above code...

Comment: I added some more info that might be relevant. But this feels like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please focus on describing the actual problem, instead of how you think you can solve it.